# How to enable java path to be used within linux system startup scripts?

Tags: java, linux, bash, apache-storm

I was trying to create a startup script for Apache Storm, which can automatically start storm supervisor upon boot.

But I constantly get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "./home/ec2-user/apache-storm-1.1.2/bin/storm.py", line 887, in 
>           main()
>         File "./home/ec2-user/apache-storm-1.1.2/bin/storm.py", line 884, in main
>           (COMMANDS.get(COMMAND, unknown_command))(*ARGS)
>         File "./home/ec2-user/apache-storm-1.1.2/bin/storm.py", line 679, in supervisor
>           jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("supervisor.childopts", cppaths)) + [
>         File "./home/ec2-user/apache-storm-1.1.2/bin/storm.py", line 153, in confvalue
>           p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE)
>         File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in **init**
>           errread, errwrite)
>         File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
>           raise child_exception
>       OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

It seems to me that the error is caused due to the inability of detecting **JAVA_HOME** and related java path.

I used [this](https://gist.github.com/johnptoohey/4360179) script with modified paths

I already configured javapath in `/.bashrc` , `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`.
But nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: looks like a path or permissions issue.

Comment: I followed this for setting up java : https://dzone.com/articles/installing-java-8-on-aws-ec2-amazon-linux-instance

Where can be a permission issue?

Comment: Can you clarify which file you would like to open?

Comment: I was trying to execute `storm <component>` using the above startup script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to declare that I rectified this issue by appending:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_171
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

to the startup script itself.